# Is there a way to block HTTP on GCP AppEngine

Tags: app-engine-flexible

I am trying to find how to block HTTP access from GCP AppEngine, not finding many details out there.
I feel that it may not possible.

Can someone shed some light on this - Via code or network setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, there is not possible to block the Http access in App Engine. You can redirect http to https traffic using the secure handler implemented in [App engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element).

For App Engine Flex, regarding blocking the port 80 alternative, you can implement a Compute VM's and set a [firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) rule and then redirect to App Engine.

Lastly, keep in mind that in the App Engine [Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-app-engine-firewall-an-easy-way-to-control-access-to-your-app) you need to specify the IP ranges that you want to allow or deny, it's not possible deny actual ports.

Comment: Thanks, I end up with the same conclusion on this.